# C string declaration

Tags: c, string

I am confused about some basics in C string declaration. I tried out the following code and I noticed some difference:

```
char* foo(){
    char* str1="string";
    char str2[7]="string";
    char* str3=(char)malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
    return str1;
    /* OR: return str2; */
    /* OR: return str3; */
    }
void main()  {
    printf("%s",foo());
    return 0;
    }
```

I made foo() return str1/2/3 one at a time, and tried to print the result in the main. str2 returned something weird, but str1 and str3 returned the actual "string".

1.Now, what's the difference between the three declarations? I think the reason why str2 didn't work is because it is declared as a local variable, is that correct?

2.Then what about str1? If the result remains after the foo() ended, wouldn't that cause memory leak?

3.I'm simply trying to write a function that returns a string in C, and use the value returned by that function for other stuff, which str declaration above should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
char* str1="string";
```

This makes `str1` a pointer; it points to the first character of the string literal.  You should define it as `const`, because you're not allowed to modify a string literal:

```
const char *str1 = "string";
```

...

```
char str2[7]="string";
```

This makes `str2` an array of `char` (not a pointer), and copies the contents of the string literal into it.  There's no need to define it as `const`; the array itself is writable.  You can also omit the size and let it be determined by the initializer:

```
char str2[] = "string";
```

Then `sizeof str2 == 7` (6 bytes for `"string"` plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'`).

This:

```
char* str3=(char)malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
```

is written incorrectly, and it shouldn't even compile; at the very least, you should have gotten a warning from your compiler.  You're casting the result of `malloc()` to type `char`. You should be converting it to `char*`:

```
char *str3 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
```

But the cast is unnecessary, and can mask errors in some cases; see question 7.7 and following in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www-c.faq.com/):

```
char *str3 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
```

But `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so you can just write:

```
char *str3 = malloc(7);
```

`malloc()` allocates memory, but it doesn't initialize it, so if you try to print the string that `str3` points to, you'll get garbage -- or even a run-time crash if the allocated space doesn't happen to contain a terminating null character `'\0'`.  You can initialize it with `strcpy()`, for example:

```
char *str3 = malloc(7);
if (str3 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strcpy(str3, "string");
```

You have to be very careful that the data you're copying is no bigger than the allocated space. (No, [`strncpy() is not the answer to this problem](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).)

`void main()` is incorrect; it should be `int main(void)`. If your textbook told you to use `void main()` find a better textbook; its author doesn't know C very well.

And you need appropriate `#include` directives for any library functions you're using: `<stdio.h>` for `printf()`, `<stdlib.h>` for `exit()` and `malloc()`, and `<string.h>` for `strcpy()`. The documentation for each function should tell you which header to include.

I know this is a lot to absorb; don't expect to understand it all right away.

I mentioned the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); it's an excellent resource, particularly section 6, which discusses arrays and pointers and the often confusing relationship between them.

As for your question 3, how to return a string from a C function, that turns out to be surprisingly complicated because of the way C does memory allocation (basically it leaves to to manage it yourself).  You can't safely return a pointer to a local variable, because the variable ceases to exist when the function returns, leaving the caller with a dangling pointer, so returning your `str2` is dangerous. Returning a string literal is ok, since that corresponds to an anonymous array that exists for the entire execution of your program. You can declare an array with `static` and return a pointer to it, or you can use `malloc()` (which is the most flexible approach, but it means the caller needs to `free()` the memory), or you can require the caller to pass in a pointer to a buffer into which your function will copy the result.

Some languages let you build a string value and simply return it from a function. C, as you're now discovering, is not one of those languages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this case, if my function has to return a string of arbitrary length, I use a char[someLength] buffer in the function, how can I return this buffer as the output?

Comment: @user1926344: First, note that your string of "arbitrary length" couldn't be longer than `someLength` bytes. Second, you'll just have to copy it to some memory region that the caller will be able to access -- which means you might as well skip the `char[someLength]` variable and copy it there directly. The region can be `static` (which has some disadvantages), or it can be `malloc()`ed, or it can be up to the caller to allocate it and pass your function a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

```
char* str1="string";
```

This creates a pointer to a literal string that will be located on either `.data` or `.text` segments and is accessible at all times. Whenever you do something like that, be sure to declare it `const`, because if you try to modify it, nasty things might happen.

```
char str2[7]="string";
```

This creates a local buffer on the stack with a copy of the literal string. It becomes unavailable once the function returns. That explains the weird result you're getting.

```
char* str3=(char)malloc(sizeof(char)*7);
```

This creates a buffer on the heap (uninitialized) that will be available until you free it. And free it you must, or you will get a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The *string literal* `"string"` is stored as a 7-element array of `char` with static extent, meaning that the memory for it is allocated at program startup and held until the program terminates.

The declaration

```
char *str1 = "string";
```

assigns the *address* of the string literal to `str1`.  Even though the variable `str1` ceases to exist when the function exits, its *value* (the address of the literal `"string"`) is still valid outside of the function.

The declaration

```
char str2[7] = "string";
```

declares `str2` as an array of `char`, and copies the *contents* of the string literal to it.  When the function exits, `str2` ceases to exist, and its contents are no longer meaningful.

The declaration

```
char *str3 = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
```

which can be simplified to

```
char *str3 = malloc(sizeof *str3 * 7);
```

allocates an uninitialized 7-byte block of memory and copies its address to `str3`.  When the function exits, the variable `str3` ceases to exist, but the memory it points to is still allocated.  As written, this *is* a memory leak, because you don't preserve the value of the pointer in the calling code.  Note that, since you don't copy anything to this block, the output in `main` will be random.

Also, unless your compiler documentation *explicitly* lists `void main()` as a legal signature for the `main` function, use `int main(void)` instead.